# Is our "Identity Server" a Good Use Case for Named Credentials and if so, how should I use Named Credentials Instead?

Tags: callout, customsetting, authentication, oauth, namedcredentials

We have a collection of microservices hosted on Azure.
In order to access these, we must first get a token from what's been described as the "identity server".

I can use this code to get the token:

```
    public EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken connect() {
        Microsoft_Azure_Settings__c settings = this.settingsSelector.selectDefault();
        HttpRequest request = this.createRequest(settings);
        HttpResponse response = (new Http()).send(request);
        return (this.httpHelper.isSuccess(response))
                ? (EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken.class)
                : null;
    }

    private HttpRequest createRequest(Microsoft_Azure_Settings__c settings) {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(settings.Connection_Token_Server_Url__c);

        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        String payload = this.httpHelper.createFormPayload(new Map<String, String>{
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
                'scope' => 'customer customer.creator ',
                'client_id' => settings.Connection_Token_Server_Client_Id__c,
                'client_secret' => settings.Connection_Token_Server_Client_Secret__c
        });

        request.setBody(payload);
        return request;
    }
```

`Microsoft_Azure_Settings__c` is a custom setting.

`EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken` is a value object which just contains:

```
public with sharing class EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken {
    public String access_token { get; set; }
    public Integer expires_in { get; set; }
    public String token_type { get; set; }
    public String scope { get; set; }
}
```

(But at the moment we only care about the value of `access_token`.)

I then consume this token to perform a callout with the following code:

```
    private List<Lead> fillIds(List<Lead> leadList, EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken bearerToken) {
        HttpRequest request = createRequest(leadList, bearerToken);
        HttpResponse response = (new Http()).send(request);
        // Do some stuff with the response...
    }

    private HttpRequest createRequest(
            List<SObject> leadList,
            EUM_DTO_AzureConnectionToken bearerToken
    ) {
        Microsoft_Azure_Settings__c settings = this.settingsSelector.selectDefault();

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(settings.User_Manager_Bulk_Url__c);

        request.setHeader('accept', 'text/plain');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearerToken.access_token);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        String body = JSON.serialize(new EUM_DTO_BulkUserIdRequest(leadList));
        request.setBody(body);
        return request;
    }
```

FWIW, in this instance, `settings.User_Manager_Bulk_Url__c` is hosted at a different subdomain than `settings.Connection_Token_Server_Url__c`.

Looking through the options for named credentials, I did not see any type where I could configure 'grant_type', 'scope', 'client_id', and 'client_secret', though this all looks like OAuth stuff to me and I realize there may be a lack of alignment between UI terminology and implementation, and/or that some portions of the authentication may still need to live in the Apex code.

Anyway, could I use named credentials for this, and if so, what do I need to do to make it work that way?