# How to create OAuthToken using Apex

Tags: apex, oauth2

I need to connect Salesforce with a 3rd party, which has a non-standard implementation of the OAuth2 flow.

Which means a number of the initial steps need to be handled using custom built endpoints to receive the `Authorisation Code` and then request the `Access Token` and `Refresh Token`.

But once I've got the `Access Token` and `Refresh Token` I'd like to store them in Salesforce in a more traditional fashion, such that the platform can use them to interact with the 3rd party API and also handle getting new `Access Tokens` when they expire.

I've found the `OAuthToken` [Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_oauthtoken.htm), but it only seems to support calls:

- describeSObjects()
- query()

So I am not clear how to add the tokens to the user.

I think I may have hit a dead end, and that it may not be possible to create an `OAuthToken` using Apex.

**Question**

1. Are there any other ways to programmatically add the `Access Token` and `Refresh Token` to the `User` such that the builtin Salesforce OAuth2 mechanisms work?

Comment: as far as I know, it is not possible to create it manually. it is created automatically when the user authorizes some connected app. Let's wait for sf mastodons to answer it :)

Comment: If you look at this code in my unanswered question, you might find what you need:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317130/is-our-identity-server-a-good-use-case-for-named-credentials-and-if-so-how-sh

Comment: Thanks @BrianKessler, but that does not help at all...

Comment: What makes it non-standard?

Answer (score 4):

`OAuthToken` object is used by `Connected Apps` for an inbound communication(when the 3rd party apps want to use salesforce APIs)

The standard approach for a third-party API that uses OAuth flow would be to use [Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_define.htm&type=5).

However, as you mentioned the API has a non-standard OAuth flow so you may have to write your own custom implementation and store `AccessToken`, `RefreshToken`, and `Validity` in a `protected custom setting` or a Custom Object with the `encrypted field`.

Here is a great example from [ffhttp-core-samples](https://github.com/financialforcedev/ffhttp-core-samples) that should help.